# What do you call the phenomenon where a rectangle □ is shown because a font lacks a glyph?

Tags: terminology, programming, typography, computing

Is there a name to describe the situation where a particular [character](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/character) is shown on a computer screen in a particular [font](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/font#Noun_2), but this font does not have a [glyph](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glyph) for this particular character?

Usually, the result looks like this: □

A kind of empty rectangle. Sometimes it shows the code for that character within the rectangle.

[image: tofubake]

What do yo call this phenomenon?

If there is no name, is there a common term referring to this "rectangle"?

Some Japanese people call this "tofubake" because rectangles look like [tofu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tofu).

*(It is not [mojibake](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mojibake). Mojibake happens when [character encoding](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/character_encoding) meta-information is lost. It is not the problem here. Using a better font solves this phenomenon, but does not solve mojibake. Selecting a character encoding solves mojibake, but does not solve this phenomenon.)*

Comment: I like `glyphlessness`. It only has two google hits, so it could use a few more.

Comment: I have just found one place where a person calls them "missing glyph squares" https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=665598

Comment: Does this question belong on http://superuser.com?

Comment: @zpletan: I hesitated a lot. I am asking for the English word to describe something. So I posted here. For the Japanese word I ask here: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5129

Comment: Fair enough—just wanted to make sure you knew there *might* be another place to ask. If you knew and decided that this was the best place, I won't be the person to say you're wrong.

Comment: By the way, the idiom should be _the font **is missing** a glyph_. *Be missing* has a special sense of _lack_, while active _misses_ implies motion in sequence, like _He missed the last step and fell._

Comment: @JohnLawler: thanks, good thing to learn about! To keep the title as short as possible I wrote "lacks", let me know if it is not correct.

Comment: _Lacks_ is probably better. No additional metaphor to trip on.

Answer (score 17):

The Unicode standard calls it a [replacement glyph](http://unicode.org/glossary/#replacement_glyph).

Comment: So the situation would be something like *glyph replacement* (e.g., *a web page rendered unreadable because of glyph replacement.*)

Comment: I would say it was rendered unreadable because of missing glyphs, but this answer sounds right to me.

Comment: In http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch05.pdf they are called "Interpretable but Unrenderable Character"... but probably nobody would understand me if I use that term.

Comment: Microsoft calls it "square" -- "Word cannot open the existing [square]" at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247028

Comment: MS also uses "Square Symbol".  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189439  Both my and Andrew's example appear to be really old articles that've been occasionally refreshed.  It'd be interesting to see if MS has gotten more consistent in new ones; but I'm not sure how to force that out of a search engine.

Comment: Very interesting answer and comments, even though I was asking for the name of the phenomenon itself. When the phenomenon happens, then a replacement glyph is used. Brett's proposition "glyph replacement" is a step closer, but unfortunately it is very general and would not convey the whole meaning in a conversation. Maybe "missing glyph replacement"?

Comment: Relevant: [What is this numbers-and-letters-in-boxes font?](http://superuser.com/questions/769170/what-is-with-this-numbers-and-letters-in-boxes-font)

Answer (score 7):

Google calls them 'tofu', too. They have a [Google Font called Noto](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Noto+Sans) which is named (see the link) for '**no to** tofu'.

> When text is rendered by a computer, sometimes there will be characters in the text that can not be displayed, because no font that supports them is available to the computer. When this occurs, small boxes are shown to represent the characters. We call those small boxes “tofu,” and we want to remove tofu from the Web.

Comment: +1 Thanks! Actually I suspect the Japan team chose this name. While the word is indeed in use in Japan (as mentioned in my question), I am not sure whether it is the best word in English.

Comment: See also: [Where is “tofu” for “font fallback box glyph” coming from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/296505/24906)

Comment: I work as a Japanese translator.  In this professional context, we call this phenomenon "tōfu-baké", as a parallel to "moji-baké".

Answer (score 5):

Glyph Replacement is too general a description (sorry, Unicode). That could mean that a font replaces 'HEAVY BLACK HEART'❤ with 'BLACK HEART SUIT' ♥ or even ampersand with plus. The phenomenon is not replacement, it is ***Glyph Failure***.  In practice, the □ codepoint is used as a Failure Glyph.

Comment: So, the word I am looking for would be "Failure Glyph", is that what you mean? Thanks!